# How to print the latest appended content of a text file?

Tags: bash, shell

My program takes a text file instead of stdout as its output. It's constantly appending new lines to the file. I can tail the file every time I want to get the latest lines of content appended. But now I want the appended content to show on my terminal simultaneously, as if my program was taking stdout as its output.

I've found out an ugly solution: print the new appended content every five seconds by backing up the content of the text file five seconds earlier and diff the current content with it, like bellow:

```
#!/bin/sh
# show the appended text of a file every 5 seconds
echo `pwd`;
while true
do
    cp $1 $1.earlier;
    sleep 5;
    echo `date`;
    diff $1 $1.earlier;
done
```

Comment: What about using tail -f?

Comment: Oh MY!!! I've never known tail has a -f option! Thanks, Rubens, for your assist in formatting the code. Thanks, Tom Ron, for telling me the correct answer so quicky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
$ tail -f file
```

From `man tail`:

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]

output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor
are equivalent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than just the last few lines of output, as well as following, you can invoke:

```
less +F $file
```

(or press `Shift-F` while viewing the file in `less`).

While following the file in less, press `Ctrl-C` to stop following but keep the file open, then `Shift-F` to follow again.